# My Tor Browser runs very slowly

Tags: load-balance

Compared with my previous use of Firefox, browsing with Tor runs very slowly. Is this because Tor Browser is loading ads that you can't se because of ad blockers?

Answer (score 2):

Well, this case can be fixed a bit - if you have a good connection. You need to add `IsolateDestAddr` to your [SocksPort](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en#SocksPort) directive in config. But be warned - if the website uses multiple (sub)domains - in some rare cases it can misbehave. The method here is to use different circuits for different destination addresses. So ads will be loaded via separate circuit and the parallelism of the whole process will be a bit better. But circuits are circuits - you're not insured from having a slow circuit in any place.

Comment: This is unlikely to improve performance, it will result in the requirement to build a (potentially very) large number of extra circuits for every site you try to load, which will increase loading times.

Comment: on 10Mbps+ on **both** sides in connection speed it used to improve speeds. On a slow ones and mobile ones - yes, you're totally right. That's why I've made a remark about the connection

Comment: It's not clear quite what the OP is asking but it seems as though it is as simple as "Why is it slower to browse the web using Tor than it is without Tor?" Answer: Because the use of Tor interposes at least three servers between you and the ultimate webpage that were not there when you were browsing directly.